# New threads are getting created on polling a directory using spring integration

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-integration

This is our spring config:

```
    <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="fileReprocessorChannelId" channel="fileReprocessorChannel"
    directory="${file.location}" scanner="headScanner">
    <int:poller cron="${reprocess.cronExpression}" max-messages-per-poll="${reprocess.maxMsgPerPoll}" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:chain id="reprocessorChain" input-channel="fileReprocessorChannel" output-channel="transformerChannel">
    <int-file:file-to-string-transformer delete-files="false" charset="UTF-8" />
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="Operation" value="${operation.fileReprocessor}" overwrite="true" />
        <int:header name="GUID" method="getGuidForReprocessing" ref="headerAttributesGenerator"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

</int:chain>

<bean id="headScanner" class="FileStreamDirectoryScanner">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>${reprocess.maxMsgPerPoll}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>${reprocess.fileAgeInMillis}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="locker" ref="nio-locker" />
</bean>

<bean id="nio-locker" class="org.springframework.integration.file.locking.NioFileLocker" />

<int:channel id="transformerChannel">
    <int:interceptors> 
    <int:wire-tap channel="loggerChannel"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
```

On running the server with around 10000 files on disk, we find the following exceprtion when around 7000 files are processed:  **java.nio.file.FileSystemException: Too many open files.**

On debugging the code, the threads seem to be created here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/endpoint/AbstractPollingEndpoint.java#L334

The huge number of threads is consuming large cpu at ~70 threads leading to application crash.

Could you please advice if there is a better way to do this (are we doing something wrong?) or if this is a known bug in the spring code?

Edit:

1. Thread dump attached:
   [Thread dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6snf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend instead the [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) if the files are in a few directories.  This likely spins up a thread too but for the directory, not each file in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

The default `taskExecutor` is a `SyncTaskExecutor` so the task runs on the scheduler thread.

The default `taskScheduler` bean only has 10 threads so you must have some other configuration that you are not showing.

Have you looked at the thread dump (`jstack pid`) to see what all these threads are doing?

Comment: **The threads seem to be trying to lock the file**:
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
 at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c37c3098> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)

Comment: I have updated the original question with the entire config. And It was 70 threads. I was misunderstanding usage of the lsof linux command. I get this exception in the logs: **java.nio.file.FileSystemException: Too many open files.**

Comment: `Too many open files`: https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/

Comment: Your Thread Dump is fully unrelated to Spring Integration. That say something about Spring AMQP. Which version do you use? How about to upgrade to the latest one: http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/?

Comment: **I'm able to reproduce this without spring amqp. is this relevant?**:  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking) at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) - parking to wait for <0x00000006c37c3098> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$Condit‌​ionObject) at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java‌​:175) at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$Condit‌​ionObject.await(Abst‌​ractQueuedSynchroniz‌​er.java:2039)

Comment: Also from the "too many files" exception, it looks like the files opened are not closed.Is there a way to close them after processing in the current setup?

Comment: Can you post the full thread dump somewhere? (Github gist, pastebin etc). I don't see how the poller could create even 70 threads.

Comment: @GaryRussell this is the full thread dump: https://gist.github.com/praveenKumar88/a42732cd709b05783ae037502b4838ad

Comment: It looks pretty normal to me; there are 10 poller threads as expected but one of might be "stuck" in solr - see `"task-scheduler-2"`; I can't comment on your other threads without seeing more configuration. If you can "reproduce without AMQP (and solr)" in the mix, you should do so.